# Reset TFS Associated Changesets after removing successful build

Tags: tfs, tfsbuild

As can be seen in the image below, TFS will automatically create a list of associated changesets that have been committed between any 2 successful builds.

However, sometimes a build will be successful but you will end up deleting it. Examples of this would be if you are modifying the build template (as this cannot be tested outside TFS), or if the build is successful, but does not actually fix the bug it attempted to.

However, if you delete a successful build, the next build will not show the changesets that occurred before the deleted build.

Does anyone know how to fix this so that the changesets associated with a deleted build are shown in the next build?

I thought that removing the label would do this, but I've tested this and it doesn't.

[image]

Comment: I, too, would like to see a solution to this.  I have discovered that **`tfsbuild destroy`** also ***does not*** appear to remove every last shred of relational information to the build(s) you are targeting for removal.

The primary evidence: the next build, by the same name/label (if you used 'destroy'), does not present you with the same list of 'Associated Changesets' that the deleted/destroyed build had listed. You get nothing.  Those changesets are still flagged somehow, somewhere.

Comment: Incidentally, this was in tfs2010